# Include Stetho only in the debug build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, stetho

I know that I can use `debugCompile` to only pull in a `dependency` for the `debug build`.  Is there a good, streamlined way to do the `code initialization` that is required as well?  Without the dependencies the other variants will fail to compile.

Comment: it is a bit complex, because you need to a/ start stetho as your app start and b/ configure your http client to transmit to stetho. You can do that by having specific versions of your classes in the debug and release source folders, I don't find that ideal, but it works

Comment: Off the cuff, in the `debug` sourceset, create a custom `Application` class that either extends `Application` (if you're not extending it elsewhere) or extends your custom `Application` (if you are using one in your main code. Register that `Application` in `android:name` of `<application>` in the `debug` manifest. In the case where you're using a custom `Application` normally, you'll probably need a `tools:replaceNode` attribute as well to tell the `debug` sourceset to replace what's in the `main` sourceset's manifest. Haven't tried this yet, though.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have a few options.

**Option 1:** Include Stetho for all builds (using `compile` instead of `debugCompile`) and only initialize it in your `Application` class for debug builds.

This is pretty easy to do. In your `Application` class, check `BuildConfig.DEBUG` like so:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Stetho.initialize(
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                    .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                    .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
                    .build()
    );
}
```

**Option 2:** Only include Stetho for debug builds, and create different `Application` classes for debug and release builds.

Thanks to Gradle, applications can have different source sets for different build variants. By default, you have release and debug build types, so you can have three different source sets:

- *debug* for code you only want in debug builds
- *release* for code you only want in release builds
- *main* for code you want in all builds

Your application code is likely all currently in the `main` source set. You can simply create a new folder called `debug` next to the `main` folder in your application and mirror the structure of your `main` folder for everything you want to add for debug builds.

In this case, you want an `Application` class in your `main` source set that doesn't reference Stetho at all.

Then you want an `Application` class in your `debug` source set that initializes Stetho like you normally would.

You can see an example of this setup in the [Stetho sample](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/tree/master/stetho-sample). Specifically, [here's the main Application class](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/blob/master/stetho-sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/stetho/sample/SampleApplication.java), and [here's the debug Application class](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/blob/master/stetho-sample/src/debug/java/com/facebook/stetho/sample/SampleDebugApplication.java). Also note that they set up manifests in each source set that selects which Application class to use.

Comment: AFAIK, the first approach won't work with `debugCompile`, as that code would be in `main` and the dependency won't exist in `main`.

Comment: Your are correct- that's why I said "Include Stetho for all builds-" I should have been more clear that this meant using `compile` instead of `debugCompile`. Thanks!

Comment: I personally prefer the second method because your stetho code might not end at just enabled it. You might want to use dumpapps, network binding and you don't want to ship untested/debug code on production.

Comment: Option 1 is not desirable, since you include library files but just not using them.

Comment: in a import ...steho... wrtie a especific annotation?

Comment: I really liked the sound of Option #2, however, I get a build failure `error: duplicate class`

Comment: the solution is to move the specific source file **out** of `main` folder and duplicate it in `debug` and `release` folders (or whatever the names of your buildtypes is) together with the necessary folder structure. Now, when you switch build types you can edit the two files.

Answer (score 97):

Check the @Tanis answer.

Also you can use something like this:

Add the library only on *debug version*.

```
dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1      
 }
```

In your Application you can do :

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    StethoUtils.install(this);
  }
}
```

Then you can create different `StethoUtils` class in the debug/release version.

In `src/debug/java/`

```
public class StethoUtils{

   public static void install(Application application){
       Stetho.initialize(
          Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(application)
            .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(application))
            .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(application))
            .build());

   }
}
```

In `src/release/java/`

```
public class StethoUtils{

   public static void install(Application application){
      // do nothing
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: If you declare any custom build types you will need to create a StethoUtils class for it as well. E.g. src/<customBuildType>/java/

Comment: This means you have to also include debug/release versions of your OkHttp interceptor code.

Answer (score 9):

Using java reflection may be a perferct idea:

```
private void initStetho() {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                try {
                   Class<?> stethoClazz = Class.forName("com.facebook.stetho.Stetho");
                    Method method = stethoClazz.getMethod("initializeWithDefaults",Context.class);
                    method.invoke(null, this);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

then we can debug compile stetho:

```
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
```

Comment: Probably don't want to be catching all of those exceptions or loading a class with a string (package name could change). Much cleaner solution is to use gradle and inject a debug variant when needed.

Comment: I believe the reflection method is the most easiest one and guaranteeing that no Stetho code is in a release build without writing code around the curch

Comment: Just make sure you Proguard the class so that it exists even once minified.

Comment: why would one use proguard in debug, and if a rare case I don't think you will need stetho

Answer (score 0):

There is more cardinal method to connect stetho or any other lib only to debug builds - using reflection: 
1) Connect your lib via debugImplementation - `debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'`
2) Implement class with only static members - DynamicClassUtils:

```
public class DynamicClassUtils {
private static final String TAG = "DynamicClassUtils";

public static void safeInvokeStaticMethod(String fullClassName, String methodName, Class<?>[] types, Object... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(fullClassName);
        Method aMethod = aClass.getMethod(methodName, types);
        aMethod.invoke(null, args);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when invoking static method, message: " + e.getMessage() + ", class: " + e.getClass());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static <T> T safeGetInstance(String fullClassName, Object... args) {
    try {
        ArrayList<Class<?>> formalParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object arg : args) {
            formalParameters.add(arg.getClass());
        }
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(fullClassName);
        Constructor<?> ctor = aClass.getConstructor(formalParameters.toArray(new Class<?>[0]));
        return (T) ctor.newInstance(args);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when creating instance, message: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3) use that class to init stetho and its network interceptor:

```
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class<?>[1];
        argTypes[0] = Context.class;
        DynamicClassUtils.safeInvokeStaticMethod("com.facebook.stetho.Stetho", "initializeWithDefaults", argTypes, this);
    }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Interceptor interceptor = DynamicClassUtils.safeGetInstance("com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor");
        if (interceptor != null) client.addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
```