# Access SQLite DB from IntelliJ for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea, android-emulator, intellij-14

How can I view the DB in IntelliJ to view its content and perform operations on it. Now I have created my tables etc but i have no idea what data is on the DB and I do not want to create queries in java to check it. seems like a slow workflow so ill wait til I know how to access the db that resides on the Android emulator im using.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)**. A nice debugging tool from **Facebook**.

Just simple to use, initialize it in your `Application` class and access your **sqlite** and even **shared preferences** from Google Chrome's developer console.

Comment: BTW, don't use it in production see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30172308/1523910) regarding that.

Comment: Right! You should use it with flavors or Dagger. Enabling it for example only on debug flavor.

Answer (score 0):

see [@alexsimo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543519/1523910).

Without root you cannot access your database on your device, unless the file is created with `a+r` permissions.

Since that is something that is unrelated to the issue, you can just [search](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=androidstudio&search=Sqlite) in plugin.jetbrains.com for `sqlite` and get a variety of plugins.

Comment: Most of those plugins are only for ultimate edition, though

Comment: alternative is to use an outside editor something like, https://github.com/sunnygoyal/jade and work on getting the database from the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database file outside of Android and use any tool to create and read it.

Then, you place it in the assets folder and setup your code to read the database from there instead of private app data. Caveat here is that a copy will be made from the assets folder to the app data, so any updates within the app won't be mirrored to the database file in the assets folder.

I believe you can access the DDMS window in Intellij/Android Studio and there is a Database Explorer there

Comment: Do you mean the app->intermediaries->assets folder? and just drag and drop it there?

What path should I use in that case?

Comment: Nope, an assets folder is either inside of or next to the res folder, can't remember

Comment: in the project structure IntelliJ created its no assets folder in res or rs its inside the "intermediaries" folder

Comment: You have to do File > New > Assets

Comment: do u mean create the assets folder inside the res or rs folder?

Comment: Not inside intermediates, but yes, if you want an assets folder, you need to create one. I think it's typically next to the res folder, not inside