# Android - dependencies and code separation (debug/release builds)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have some code in my android application which I intend to keep only in debug-builds.

I am aware of this approach:

```java
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //code here
}
```

However, the problem is that my code relies on external dependencies which I would also like to keep in debug builds only :

```java
debugCompile "dependency1"

//this wont compile in release mode
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //code which references dependency1 
}
```

Given that there is no conditional compilation in java, are there any solutions besides commenting out blocks of code manually every time (which is obviously a huge hassle)?

EDIT:
Egor [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097329/5790273) me in the right direction and after doing some more reasearch on "source sets" I found an answer which PRECISELY describes my situation and provides an excellent solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483962/5790273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code you only want to compile in debug mode under "src/debug/java", as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets). Gradle allows you to use multiple source sets per build type and flavor, and will only compile those that are relevant for the build configuration.