# How do I remove a library from a Prod build flavor?

Tags: android, gradle

I use Stetho for my Android app. I wish to remove this whenever I create a Release build or a Prod Flavour... Either is fine.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that a library should only be used for specific builds by using `debugImplementation` instead of `implementation` in your build.gradle file. In fact, you can specify any combination of build type and/or flavor. For more details, see [Specify Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#dependencies) in the Android documentation.

Comment: But then, I will get: `error: package com.facebook.stetho does not exist`

Comment: @Subby Please create a [mcve] that produces that error.

Comment: What code exactly? The problem here is that if I state in my gradle file `debugImplementation`, the library successfully is removed on a release build. Good. The problem though is that the code that uses that library within the app will show as an error since gradle removed the library.

Comment: So it throws an exception on this: `import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;`

Comment: @Subby Start a new project and write just enough code to illustrate the problem. Be sure to read the link I gave for tips. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172308/include-stetho-only-in-the-debug-build-variant for more suggestions about solving your specific problem.