# android library module how to bring in stetho only in debug build

Tags: android, android-library, stetho

Having android library module, in debug build it would like to use the stetho, bot no in release build.
I guess it could add dependency of

```
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'

or using 
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'. // with latest version
debugImplementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
```

The question is in where the code need to take the StethoInterceptor

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
    .build()
```

how does it compile in release build that there is no stetho dependency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include Stetho only in the debug build variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172308/include-stetho-only-in-the-debug-build-variant)

Comment: If stetho doesn't provide special artifact for release build then you shouldn't be using that dependency per build type. Instead you can try conditionally adding like: `if(BuildType.Debug) { add stetho }`

Comment: it does not compile if no dependency `.addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())`

Answer (score 0):

Please call the below `checkAndInitStetho()` method in your `application` class:

```
public YourApplication extends Application {

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        checkAndInitStetho();
    }


private void checkAndInitStetho() {
        //Stetho integration
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
            try {
                SyncTask.executeAndWait(() -> Stetho.initialize(
                        Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(YourApplication.this)
                                .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(YourApplication.this))
                                .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(YourApplication.this))
                                .build()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGE(LOG_TAG, "Error on checkAndInitStetho()", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when you create the `OkHttpClient.Builder`, you should check whether its `debug` mode as below:-

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new 
                 StethoInterceptor());
 }
```

Please go through the [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) for the `application` class

Comment: the library does not have `application`, the only code it may need is somewhere to do `.addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())``

Comment: Not that, your android app has Application class rt? otherwise, you can do while the concrete() of your first activity executes. Best do in Application class

Comment: the library does not no know who is the hosting app. if no dependency to stetho, the `Stetho.` is not resolved.